# R select columns from DF given duplicate count

Tags: r

I have a data frame with a few hundred variable columns (both character and numeric) and about 5-6k rows.

Some of the variables have many unique values, I want to to count the unique values in the character columns and then create a new data frame with only those columns that have values repeating more than X number of times (eliminate char columns that only have unique values or few repeating ones).

```
   var1 | var 2 | var 3|
1.  asf    5       al   
2.  asf    3       br
3.  ab     2       aa
4.  ar     1       bb
5.  asf    10      cc
6.  asf    18      ae
7.  bf     20      sf
8.  asf    21      pb
```

I already made the date frame that only has the character columns which now looks like this:

```
   var1 | var 3 | 
1.  asf    al   
2.  asf    br
3.  ab     aa
4.  ar     bb
5.  asf    cc
6.  asf    ae
7.  bf     sf
8.  asf    pb
```

I now need to be able to get a count of duplicate values per column and then select only those columns that exceed a certain count for duplicate values, lets say 5 for the example above - so I would want to create a data frame having only var1 as it has 'asf' repeating 5 times.

An additional note if of consequence some variables have a lot of NAs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with `dplyr`. First we select the data by those columns which are factors (change to `is.character` if your data is `character` rather than `factor`), then find those that have a maximum frequency greater than or equal to 5:

```
library(dplyr)
dta %>% select(which(sapply(., is.factor))) %>%
        select(which(sapply(., function(x) max(table(x)) >= 5)))

  var1
1  asf
2  asf
3   ab
4   ar
5  asf
6  asf
7   bf
8  asf
```

Comment: I think you can do just `indx <- sapply(df, function(x) max(table(x))) >= 5 ; df[indx]` as the OP already selected the non-numeric columns

Comment: it works, but the dplyr version takes care of removing the numeric columns too. Also, no pipes in yours.